# The difference between 'ping' and 'wget' in relation to hostname resolution

Tags: dns, wget, hostname, ping

When I used `wget`, the hostname resolution is ok

```
root:here cd$ wget https://gfe.cit.api.here.com/1/layer_put.json?layer_id=123&app_id=x2&app_code=x1
```

The result is

```
Resolving gfe.cit.api.here.com... 52.51.134.116, 54.154.19.134, 52.208.9.155
Connecting to gfe.cit.api.here.com|52.51.134.116|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2016-12-24 13:18:47 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

But when I used `ping`

```
ping https://gfe.cit.api.here.com/1/layer_put.json?layer_id=123&app_id=x2&app_code=x1
```

The result is

```
cannot resolve https://gfe.cit.api.here.com/1/layer_put.json?layer_id=123: Unknown host
```

The hostname resolution failed, what's the difference between `wget` and `ping`?

Comment: The question, as formulated, is comparable to asking what is the difference between a car and a lawmower.  The only similarity between the two is that they roll.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The edited question makes it clearer but the original question was already asking about the hostname resolution issue, not about the general difference between both commands used here.

Answer (score 10):

Answering to:

> What is the difference between 'ping' and 'wget' in relation to hostname resolution

`Ping` expects either an IP address or a hostname as parameter. You are giving it a full URL which it tries to resolve as a hostname and fails. With everything but the fully qualified named stripped, the `ping` command is able to check the connection (and fails in my following test, maybe because the `ICMP` request is blocked or because the server is down):

```
$ ping gfe.cit.api.here.com

Pinging cle2-cit.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com [54.154.19.134] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

For the general difference between `ping` and `wget`, see Alec's answer.

For a probable reason explaining the Error 400, see roaima's one.

Comment: I like the way you put everything in perspective.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question you actually asked. `wget` takes a URL, but `ping` takes a hostname. Your URL is comprised of a protocol (`https`), a hostname (`gfe.cit.api.here.com`), a path (`/1/layer_put.json`), and three encoded parameters (`layer_id=123&app_id=x2&app_code=x1`). There are other items that may appear in a URL, such as an authentication and a port.

Only the hostname component is acceptable for the `ping` command.

The `wget` command then opens a TCP/IP connection to the port expected by the protocol (`443/tcp` in the case of `https`) and uses the HTTP protocol to retrieve content from the specified URL.

The `ping` command uses ICMP to send a *ping* request to the specified host, which then returns the *echo reply* response. These are ICMP packet types 8 and 0, respectively.

---

Now, the underlying reason for your `wget` failing is that you haven't quoted the parameter to `wget`, so the shell parses it. The `&` character in the middle of the URL tells the shell to run everything up to that point in the background. It then immediately runs the remaining two parts of the line, and promptly errors out.

Use single quotes around your URL and it'll probably work as you intended.

So we have

```
wget -O layer_put.json 'https://gfe.cit.api.here.com/1/layer_put.json?layer_id=123&app_id=x2&app_code=x1'

ping -c3 gfe.cit.api.here.com
```

Comment: I think your answer is useful, but I suspect people vote it down because it doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: @Julie, thanks, yes I'm sure you right. I've finally got round to rewriting it.

Answer (score 5):

Wget is primarily used for downloading over HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP so by default will use TCP for connections. Ping uses a protocol called *ICMP*, which is a basically saying "hello" to the host and seeing if it responds. ICMP does not use a port, which is what http:// means. It tells "the computer "open a connection on port 80," and for HTTPS port 443. As ICMP does not use ports, ping expects only and IP address, but wget established a TCP connection and downloads a file.

Comment: Both wget and ping might use name resolution before attempting to connect to the target host. Ping isn't restricted to use an IP address.

Comment: `http` doesn't just mean use a port. It tells the client to use the HTTP protocol over TCP, defaulting to port 80. Without the protocol you still wouldn't get a result.